# Can you use the same socket to send the request to server from which you previously send in c++

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2010, sockets, visual-c++, client

Suppose you connected to a server through socket connection and for onetime you send the request to the server and receive the response then again you try to send the request to the server but send(); returns -1 because server was down after a while server comes up,can you use the same socket to send request to the server ?

Comment: You've answered your own question. If send() returns -1 because the connection went down, the connection is down, and you need a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, when you get the error the connection is no longer valid. Once a connection is invalidated, you should just close the socket; you can't reuse it for a new connection. If the server has gone down, it has no memory of the parameters of the original connection (e.g. port numbers); you need to open a new connection so that the client and server will be in sync.

Comment: Incorrect. When you get the error *the socket remains open.* However the error condition indicates that the *connection* is broken. At this point there is nothing useful you can do with the socket except close it, which I repeat is *not* automatic, and create and connect a new one.